# Removing an old Frontpage website from a domain and uploading a new (static) one

Tags: web-hosting, microsoft

I've been asked to refresh a really old website (made I think around 2000 with Frontpage) with a new version.

So, after developing it locally, I jumped on the client's FTP and saw an unfamiliar folder structure: it's the damned Frontpage!

Here's a screenshot of the folder structure:
[image]

And there's a bunch of html files, omitted to save space.

I have no experience on Frontpage (luckily I guess), but my question is simple:

- Is it safe to delete everything in the root of the host and upload my new website?
- If anything goes wrong, will I be able to simple re-upload the old website and restore everything as it was before? I've read that uploading Frontpage websites via ftp is discouraged.

The website is hosted on a Linux server and has no database, it's a plain simple web hosting

Answer (score 1):

> Is it safe to delete everything in the root of the host and upload my new website?

Yes. None of those directories are required to the webserver to operate.

> If anything goes wrong, will I be able to simple re-upload the old website and restore everything as it was before? I've read that uploading Frontpage websites via ftp is discouraged.

Probably. FrontPage at its best was not 100% stable so even if you used FrontPage you could have issues restoring it. IIRC uploading the site back via FTP was problematic. But if you do run into issues your best bet is to figure out why the new site isn't working rather than trying to restore the old one.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.
Since those folders are not required by the webserver itself (which runs on Apache) I should be able to upload just the static HTML files back with no issues, I think.

Let's see how it goes